# Будет ли вызываться метод в ларавел если поместить его в строку?

Tags: php, laravel, очередь

Возможно это very bad, но посмотрим что скажете вы и какие есть решения.
Я пишу универсальный job для уведомлений. Есть поле действия "action" и мне нужно в зависимости от того, что передадут в экземпляр (какой метод), то и подставлять в место метода.
Вместо строки я конечно поставлю туда переменную, но сути много не меняет, ибо в переменную буду присваивать строку по типу "follow", "entity" и т.д. (внимание на скриншот)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это действительно очень плохо и не работает, то подскажите пожалуйста как сделать это правильно?

Comment: Самый главный вопрос будет ли это работать такой прописью NotificationTypes::"FOLLOW" или же работает только NotificationTypes::FOLLOW?

Comment: Самый главный вопрос - нафига? Чем тебе плоха передача каких-то значений и затем сравнение с эталонными данными через `if`? `if action == 'a' this->a()`?

Comment: @u_mulder, как минимум по той причине, что таких поля 2 и значений в них много. Мне прописывать сотню if? Тут даже свитчём будет пелена сравнений выглядящих страшно(из-за количества конечно). Поэтому я и спрашиваю будет ли работать как я спросил или же реально единственный вариант - простыня сравнений?

Comment: NotificationTypes::"FOLLOW" - это метод у вас или переменная?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру, да, ошибся. Это у меня переменная

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен что правильно вас понял. Будет, в случае если передадим полный `namespace` класса и название метода, к примеру у нас есть класс

```
class MyClass {

  public static $myVar = 'classVar';

  public static function foo() {
    echo 'foo method';
  }

  public static function bar() {
    echo 'bar method';
  }

}
```

Инициализируем `$action`

```
$method1 = 'foo';
$method2 = 'bar';
$action = [
  'type' => MyClass::class . "::{$method1}",
  'entity' => MyClass::class . "::{$method2}",
];
```

Вызываем методы, которые указали в `$action` ранее

```
call_user_func($action['type']); // echo foo method
call_user_func($action['entity']); // echo bar method
```

В случае, если нужно будет передать аргументы в эти методы то используем `call_user_func_array()`, например

```
call_user_func_array($action['entity'], [$a,$b,$c]);
```

Более подробно про эти методы можно прочитать тут [call_user_func()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php), [call_user_func_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php)

**UPD**
В случае с переменной - чуть сложнее, получить значение можно будет через рефлексию

```
$myVarName = 'myVar';
$reflect = new ReflectionClass(MyClass::class);
echo  $reflect->getStaticPropertyValue($myVarName); // echo classVar
```

Comment: Я кажется понял. Если есть какие-то нюансы исходя из моей ошибки, что Follow - переменная, то поправьте пожалуйста, но а так я догнал вроде как. Большое вам спасибо)

Comment: Протестирую) Если удастся, то сделаю этот ответ правильным решением вопроса)

Comment: @Vladislav Обновил ответ

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста. Я пытаюсь создать экземпляр ReflectionClass в моём классе который должен получить информацию о классе NotificationTypes, но получаю ошибку, что Class "App\Jobs\ReflectionClass" not found.

Comment: В данный класс в котором я создаю этот экземпляр указан namespace, указано расположение NotificationTypes, но я всё равно получаю ошибку. Пробовал создать двумя способами: $this->type = new ReflectionClass('NotificationTypes'); и $this->type = new ReflectionClass(NotificationTypes::class);

Comment: Я очень долго мучался с рефлексией, но как оказалось всё что написано Вадимом до UPD также работает с константами класса. С рефлексией у меня не сложилось не заработало и поэтому я попробовал прописать NotificationTypes::class . "::{$type}" и оно заработало, я получил нужное значение константы) Спасибо Вадиму)